# Not able to retrive file events info in osquery-python

Tags: python, osquery

I have a task to write a python program to retrive file and process information using osquery while program is running and we perform any operation on file at background.
I have written the below code but it does'nt show any output.

```
import osquery

instance= osquery.SpawnInstance()
instance.open()

while True:
  results = instance.client.query("SELECT fe.action,fe.md5,p.gid,p.name,pe.mode FROM processes p JOIN process_events pe ON p.pid = pe.pid join file_events fe on pe.path=fe.target_path where fe.action='open' OR 'update' OR 'rename' OR 'remove' OR 'close' OR 'read' OR 'write';")

  if results.response:
   print(results.response)

instance.connection=None
```

Comment: Does your SQL query work in the SQL client and return a result?

Comment: No, whenever I tried to fetch data from evented tables it doesn't return any info.

Comment: so why would you expect anything to be printed?

Answer (score 0):

If you are querying evented tables, you need to connect with the osquery's daemon. Try this:
https://github.com/osquery/osquery-python#connect-to-an-existing-socket

More info about evented tables:
https://osquery.readthedocs.io/en/stable/development/pubsub-framework/